# Allow moderators to see failed audits that haven't led to an automated review ban

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, review-audits, moderators

Moderators have access to a user's profile/history to look at things necessary to perform our role - one of those is reviewing stuff. The system currently now only records on a user's profile if they were banned from review - but not if they failed audits.

We can work it out of course - but it's a lot of clicking through and combining stuff from other screens together.

Can we add to a user's profile "failed audit"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yup - was aware of that now 3 year old post - was kinda hoping that a new and more specific one would bump the idea back :)